# $\mathcal{A}:= \left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \mathbb{N} \right\}$ sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, algebras

Let $\Omega$ be a set $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset$ whenever $m \neq n$ and $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n = \Omega$. Consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ defined by:

$\mathcal{A}:= \left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

To show: $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

My attempt:

- Choose $I = \mathbb{N}$ then $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ and by assumption $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \Omega$
- Let $A\in \mathcal{A}$ then $A=\bigcup_{i \in \lambda} A_i $ for $\lambda \subset \mathbb{N}$. Now $A^c = (\bigcup_{i \in \lambda} A_i)^c = \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \lambda}A_j $. This is true because  $A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset$ whenever $m \neq n$. But since ($\mathbb{N} \setminus \lambda) \subset \mathbb{N} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{A}$
- Let $A_{I_n} \in \mathcal{A}$. Then $A_{I_n} = \bigcup_{i \in I_n}A_i.$ But then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{I_n} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A_i$ which is by assumption in $\mathcal{A}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Why is the subscript $n$  there twice in the notation $(A_n)_n$? Also does $I_n$ mean :the identity function on $n$ (regarding $n$ as nonnegative or ositive integers up to $n$)? Or is $I_n$ simply the integers in the latter?

Comment: @coffeemath  $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ I think this clarifies it. A sequence $A_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. $I_n$ should be here just a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ but depends on $n$ since I'll have to show that it is stable under countable union and therefore I'm iterating with this $n$ over the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since your proposed sigma algebra consists of the various unions of a specific list of pairwise disjoint sets, it is obvious anyway that if you take a countable union of those it will be in your proposed sigma algebra, merely because that proposed algebra was already *defined* to be the collection of all subsets of the power set of the basic collection of pairwise disjoint sets.

It still seems there might be a simpler way to say the above; the more I look at it my version seems overly complicated.

Comment: After reading your answer it became clear for me why it is obvious. I think we were just given this exercise to get familiar with the definition of $\sigma$-algebras and prove it theoretically.